# Как использовать здесь метод chaining? Нужно решить это без создания полей, не разрывая цепочки методов

Tags: методы, потоки-данных, scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern selectWords = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-я0-9]+");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8").useDelimiter(selectWords);
    List<String> buf = new ArrayList<>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        buf.add(sc.next());
    }
    Stream<String> words = buf.stream();
    Map<String, Long> frqWords = words.map((s) -> s.toLowerCase())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>> output = frqWords.entrySet().stream();
    output.sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, Long> e) -> e.getKey()))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, Long> e) -> 
e.getValue()).reversed())
            .limit(10)
            .forEach((Map.Entry<String, Long> e) -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
}
```

Comment: Не хотел бы я поддерживать подобный сложносочиненный код, да еще и без комментариев .. мысли вслух.

Comment: В задании было сказано написать программу, читающую из System.in текст в кодировке UTF-8, подсчитывающую в нем частоту появления слов, и в конце выводящую 10 наиболее часто встречающихся слов. 
Словом будем считать любую непрерывную последовательность символов, состоящую только из букв и цифр.

Comment: Решение через стримы без циклов и условных операторов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема данного кода в том, что первый же цикл для чтения слов при помощи сканера из потока ввода является бесконечным, то есть, его нужно ограничить хотя бы по общему количеству слов. Если бы чтение выполнялось из файла, такой проблемы не возникло бы.

Также излишне накапливать введенные слова в списке, для которого затем вызывается `stream()`.

Таким образом можно выделить основной функционал по обработке потока слов `Stream<String>`, чтобы вывести топ N слов по частоте.

Также следует определить, как выводить слова с одинаковой частотой.  Если нужно сохранить порядок вхождения во входном потоке, следует использовать `LinkedHashMap::new` в качестве провайдера мапы.  Если нужно отсортировать дополнительно слова по алфавиту, можно использовать `TreeMap::new`

```java
public static void printTopN(int n, Stream<String> words) {
    words.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            w -> w, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()
        )) // Map<String, Long>
        .entrySet() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>>
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(n)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Соответственно, такой метод можно вызвать с использованием генератора `Stream::generate`, с наложением ограничений:

```java
private static Scanner scanner() {
    return new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")
        .useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-я0-9]+");
}

public static void main1(String ... args) {
    Scanner scanner = scanner();
    printTopN(10, Stream.generate(() -> scanner.next())
        .takeWhile(w -> !"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(w) && scanner.hasNext())
        .limit(100)
    );
}
```

Или же можно создать поток слов на основании сканера с использованием `StreamSupport` и `Spliterator` как показано в ответе на основном SO: [How to make scanner strings into a Stream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29611792/13279831)

```java
private static Stream<String> streamScanner(Scanner scanner) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(
        scanner, Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL
        ), false
    );    
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    printTopN(10, streamScanner(scanner())
        .takeWhile(Predicate.not("quit"::equalsIgnoreCase))
        .limit(100)
    );
}
```

Тест:

```
1 33 2 1 p 1 2 33 44 q w e 1 1 2 33 333 11 22 w e 1 d dd quit
1=6
33=3
2=3
w=2
e=2
p=1
44=1
q=1
333=1
11=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё! До меня дошло, как это исправить. Голова просто тяжелая после праздников. Вот так это можно сделать.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")
        .useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-я0-9]+");
    List<String> buf = new ArrayList<>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        buf.add(sc.next());
    }
```

Comment: И что именно вам здесь удалось исправить?  Если что, праздники в полном разгаре :)